# Unable to get radio button value from html content + iOS + objective c + webpage

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am loading one html content on webpage , It has radio buttons, check boxes, and text fields, user enter choices.  After that, when user clicks any button on screen(not on webpage), I want to retrieve all selected values like this - (currently it is returning wrong value for radio button (Aantal stalling op station))

```
Aantal stalling op station=1&Aantal stalling op station=Meer dan 1&Openingstijden_MA=THis is text field&Openingstijden_DI=&Openingstijden_WO=&Openingstijden_DO=&Openingstijden_VR=&Openingstijden_ZA=&Openingstijden_ZO=&Bewaakt service=Bewaakt&Fietsreparatie service=Fietsreparatie&Fietsverhuur service=Fietsverhuur&Ovfiets service=OV-fiets&Eerste gratis service=Eerste 24 u gratis&
```

HTML Content - 
            https://shrib.com/#HTMLProblem02thAugustPrblm

```js
function collectForm () {var Result = "";var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName ("input");for( i = 0 ; i < inputs.length ; i++ ){var inp = inputs[i];Result += inp.name + "=" +inp.value + "&";}return Result;}
```

```css
.aantal-stalling-template-table td {display: block;width: 100%;} 
h2 { font-size: small; } 
body, p , td , input , h1 , h2 , h3 , li { font-family: "Arial"; }
```

```html
<form><p>Vul de benodigde gegevens in.</p><p>&nbsp;</p><h2 class="pmMenuTopPas b-pmProductHeaders">AANPASSEN:</h2><table border="0" class="aantal-stalling-tempalte-table"><tbody><tr><td>
<p class="text">Aantal stalling op station:</p><ul class="tempalte-radio-list">
<li class="item"><input name="Aantal stalling op station" id="aantal_stalling_1" class="afleveradres" type="radio" value="1" /><label for="aantal_stalling_1">1</label>
<div class="check"></div></li><li class="item"><input name="Aantal stalling op station" id="aantal_stalling_meer" class="afleveradres" type="radio" value="Meer dan 1" /><label for="aantal_stalling_meer">Meer dan 1</label>
<div class="check">
<div class="inside"></div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<p class="text">Openingstijden:</p>
<input name="Openingstijden_MA" placeholder="MA:" class="opening-date" type="text" /><input name="Openingstijden_DI" placeholder="DI:" class="opening-date" type="text" /><input name="Openingstijden_WO" placeholder="WO:" class="opening-date" type="text" /><input name="Openingstijden_DO" placeholder="DO:" class="opening-date" type="text" /><input name="Openingstijden_VR" placeholder="VR:" class="opening-date" type="text" /><input name="Openingstijden_ZA" placeholder="ZA:" class="opening-date" type="text" /><input name="Openingstijden_ZO" placeholder="ZO:" class="opening-date" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<p class="text">Services:</p>
<ul class="tempalte-checkbox-list">
<li class="item"><input name="Bewaakt service" id="bewaakt_service" class="afleveradres" type="checkbox" value="Bewaakt" /><label for="bewaakt_service">Bewaakt</label>
<div class="check"></div>
</li>
<li class="item"><input name="Fietsreparatie service" id="fietsreparatie_service" class="afleveradres" type="checkbox" value="Fietsreparatie" /><label for="fietsreparatie_service">Fietsreparatie</label>
<div class="check">
<div class="inside"></div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="item"><input name="Fietsverhuur service" id="fietsverhuur_service" class="afleveradres" type="checkbox" value="Fietsverhuur" /><label for="fietsverhuur_service">Fietsverhuur</label>
<div class="check"></div>
</li>
<li class="item"><input name="Ovfiets service" id="ovfiets_service" class="afleveradres" type="checkbox" value="OV-fiets" /><label for="ovfiets_service">OV-fiets</label>
<div class="check">
<div class="inside"></div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="item"><input name="Eerste gratis service" id="eerste_gratis_service" class="afleveradres" type="checkbox" value="Eerste 24 u gratis" /><label for="eerste_gratis_service">Eerste 24 u gratis</label>
<div class="check"></div>
</li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table></form>
```

Please feel free to ask if you have any question, I tried it 2 days but didn't get success. Thanks in advance.